# Calculate SUM from one table and display columns from another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, Employee, and Transaction

**Transaction**

| tID | cID | carID | eID | tDate | PickupDate | ReturnDate | Amount_Due |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

**Employee**

| eID | fName | lName | Job | Manager | Hired |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I need to calculate the commission (2.5%) and display that along with fName and lName.

I've calculated the commission, I think I've done the join correctly but can't quite figure out how to add in a SELECT to show the other two columns.

```
SELECT t.Amount_Due
    , SUM(t.Amount_Due*0.025) AS Commission
FROM [Transaction] t
JOIN Employee e ON t.eID = e.eID
GROUP BY t.Amount_Due
```

Comment: Doesn't really make much sense: how can you group and sum the same column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping by the wrong columns, and you are trying to select `Amount_Due` and aggregate it at the same time:

```sql
SELECT e.fName
    , e.lName,
    , SUM(t.Amount_Due * 0.025) AS Commission
    FROM [Transaction] t
    JOIN Employee e 
      ON t.eID = e.eID
    GROUP BY e.ID, e.fName, e.lName;
```

Comment: @marc_s Of course, just not the other way round, all *select* columns must be in the *group by*

Answer (score 1):

Probably just a typo - the `JOIN` should probably be `ON t.eID = e.eId`. You need to include both tables (table aliases) involved - you're currently just using the `t.eID` twice.

Try this :

```
SELECT 
    t.Amount_Due, SUM(t.Amount_Due*0.025) AS Commission
FROM 
    [Transaction] t
JOIN 
    Employee e ON t.eID = e.eID
GROUP BY 
    t.Amount_Due
```

As pointed out by @charlieface - it seems very odd that you're **summing** the `Amount_due`, and at the same time trying to **group by** that same column..... my best guess is that you probably want to **group by** the employee, based on their `eID` - so use something like this:

```
SELECT 
    e.eID, e.fName, e.lName, SUM(t.Amount_Due*0.025) AS Commission
FROM 
    [Transaction] t
JOIN 
    Employee e ON t.eID = e.eID
GROUP BY
    e.eID, e.fName, e.lName
```

for that.

Comment: Ah, missed the typo, thanks. I also want to be able to see fName and lName of the employee for each transaction.

Comment: Doesn't really make much sense: how can you group and sum the same column

Comment: @Charlieface: agreed - I was wondering about that too - I *assume* (without really knowing) that the OP wanted to group by **employee** (based on `eID`) - rather than amount due .... but again: that's just a total guess on my behalf

Comment: Yes you are correct @marc_s, I overlooked the group and sum the same column. That makes sense. Very helpful thank you.

Comment: note: you can do SUM(t.Amount_Due)*0.025   , (A+B+C)xD = AxD + BxD + CxD    not nessecary multiply every rows and your minimize round ;)